# Convert Day_Duration to Integer in Ada

Tags: ada

I have the current time in seconds like this:

```
The_Seconds  : DAY_DURATION;
```

And I wish to convert it to an `Integer`. How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the definition of `DAY_DURATION`?

If it's just in seconds it might be an integral type so `Integer( The_Seconds )` would work; if it's a `Float` that syntax should also work, but you'll have to give some thought to whether to truncate, round, or ceiling it before conversion [look into the floating-point Attributes].

Comment: Check out package `Ada.Calendar` - [ARM 9.6 (7) ff](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-6.html#p7).

Answer (score 2):

Day_Duration is a subtype of Duration, which is a fixed point type declared in [package Standard](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-1.html#p43).

Just type convert it.

Comment: Marc, did you know that from Ada 2012 you can link to paras in the ARM using `#p<para num>`? In this case, you could have said `#p43`. Saves a load of time!